# Выражение "ишь ты"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Задумался: а откуда пошло выражение "ишь ты!"? Что значило слово "ишь" изначально?

Answer (score 4):

По Фасмеру происхождение объясняется так: :"Ишь ты! – межд. удивления и порицания. Из вишь и далее из ви́дишь – 2 л. ед. ч. наст. вр. или др.-русск. форма 2-го л. ед. ч. повел. накл. вижь, ст.-слав. виждь; см. Преобр. I, 277."

Answer (score 2):

> Что значило слово "ишь" изначально?

Оно значит: *видишь, видишь ли, видите ли*.

В разговорной речи *"видишь"* сокращали до *"вишь"*. А от *"вишь"* образовалось *"ишь"*.